# Why does Kubernetes pod CPU usage vary drastically between nodes (DaemonSets)?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, coredns, metallb

Preface: I'm a Kubernetes novice standing up their own cluster at home, I have 1 master and 3 worker nodes.

I'm struggling to determine why some of my pods managed by DaemonSets are using more CPU than their counterparts on other nodes.

Here's an excerpt from `kubectl top pod --all-namespaces` results:

NAMESPACE              NAME                                          CPU(cores)   Node
kube-system            coredns-p7xkg                                 20m          Master
kube-system            coredns-ztwnn                                 **66m          Worker 1**
kube-system            coredns-2n44b                                 **68m          Worker 2**
kube-system            coredns-smhnb                                 15m          Worker 3
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-j4f6l                         9m           Master
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-fwwqg                         **67m          Worker 1**
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-sm7g6                         **44m          Worker 2**
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-qk9vq                         11m          Worker 3
metallb-system         speaker-lfp8n                                 22m          Master
metallb-system         speaker-6plw9                                 **100m         Worker 1**
metallb-system         speaker-gt4fm                                 **99m          Worker 2**
metallb-system         speaker-bntfk                                 27m          Worker 3

As you can see above, the issue exists with workers 1 and 2 across the 3 different DaemonSets.

Master features: controller manager, api server, dashboard and metrics scraper, metallb controller, in addition to the above DaemonSet pods
Worker #1 features: the above + kube proxy
Worker #2 features: mariadb, metrics server, elastic quickstart es/kb/operator
Worker #3 features: phpmyadmin, gitea, splunk, nexus

I suspect there may be some networking issue causing the high CPU usage on worker nodes # 1 and #2 but nothing in the pod logs is
jumping out at me.

CoreDNS v1.7.0
Flannel v0.13.1-rc1
MetalLB v0.9.5

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what to check to get to the bottom this?

Thanks in advance!